# elasticsearch downgrade challenge: shard allocated for local recovery (post api), should exists, but doesn't

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-indices

After I uninstalled elasticsearch 0.9.x through `brew uninstall elasticsearch` I installed elasticsearch 0.20.6 through `brew install elasticsearch-0.20`.

When I start the server through

```
elasticsearch -f -D es.config=/usr/local/opt/elasticsearch-0.20/config/elasticsearch.yml
```

the server endlessly logs the following exception:

```
[2014-09-04 18:06:14,613][WARN ][cluster.action.shard     ] [Jann] sending failed shard for [sensei_cucumber_news_feeds][0], node[gne6S-UYQPWnR9FqtKg_mw], [P], s[INITIALIZING], reason [Failed to start shard, message [IndexShardGatewayRecoveryException[[sensei_cucumber_news_feeds][0] shard allocated for local recovery (post api), should exists, but doesn't]]]
[2014-09-04 18:06:14,634][WARN ][indices.cluster          ] [Jann] [sensei_cucumber_news_feeds][0] failed to start shard
org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.IndexShardGatewayRecoveryException: [sensei_cucumber_news_feeds][0] shard allocated for local recovery (post api), should exists, but doesn't
    at org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.local.LocalIndexShardGateway.recover(LocalIndexShardGateway.java:122)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.IndexShardGatewayService$1.run(IndexShardGatewayService.java:174)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

I'm also wondering why the indices still exists. The indices should have been deleted after uninstallation, right?

`localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty=true` shows red signal:

```
{
  "cluster_name": "elasticsearch_gawlim",
  "status": "red",
  "timed_out": false,
  "number_of_nodes": 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes": 1,
  "active_primary_shards": 0,
  "active_shards": 0,
  "relocating_shards": 0,
  "initializing_shards": 4,
  "unassigned_shards": 867
}
```

When I try to execute a search request on the server I get

```
SearchPhaseExecutionException Failed to execute phase [query], total failure; shardFailures: No active shards
```

Deleting indices queries work.

Answer (score 0):

I manually deleted the indices through the following command and now it works:

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/index_name'
```